# How to reduce noise in old, low-light DV-8 video

Tags: video, noise-reduction

I have some old, low-light, pretty noisy DV8 video that I'd like to clean up. What is the best tool/technique to remove noise from low-light scenes?

I also want to change the gamma correction to bring out the details - should I do that before or after I run any noise reduction?

I saw that Photoshop CS5 had some pretty amazing noise reduction capability, and that the new CS6 allows you to edit video, so my original question was "can I use CS6 to reduce the noise?"  But I'm ok with making the question more general.

Comment: You'll need the Extended version of Photoshop, ie. Photoshop CS5 Extended, to edit video.

Comment: I'm somewhat intrigued by the question, but I suspect it would get better results if it were migrated to avp.stackexchange, where video-related questions belong.

Comment: Well, I posted it in the photo forum because my goal was to ask Photoshop experts who I assumed would know the most about the new Photoshop CS6 capabilities.  In this forum I'd want to ask a different question, so I guess I'll rewrite my question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as DragonLord said, with the extended edition.

And assuming it's in a format (AVI, MOV etc. that Photoshop supports.

Once open, select Filter > Convert for Smart Filters.   Then run any filter, including noise reduction, and it will apply it to all frames.   Then Export > Render to Video.